# flask-resful api jwt_required specific identity

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jwt, flask-restful

Is there a way to restrict the API endpoint with the @jwt_required decorator looking at only one identity?

Right now, I create the JWT with the identity of an admin user = 1 and standard user = 0.
On my route, I have something like this:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
@jwt_required
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if get_jwt_identity()[1] == 1:
```

Is there a cleaner way to check the jwt_identity and perform whatever is defined there for the route? Not sure if my approach is the best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom decorator to hold that logic: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_decorators/